# Como faço para encontrar parte de um elemento dentro de um array? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo um filter dentro de um array para pegar parte do elemento conforme  digitado na minha busca onde:

```
array.filter(row => row.cnpj.indexOf(search) >= 0)
```

Considerando 'search' a busca digitada, se tiver dentro do array, cnpj com valor nulo vai dar erro no indexOf:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null
```

Como eu faço esse filter ignorando os valores nulos ou então existe uma maneira melhor de fazer isso?

Comment: Será que podias mostrar o resto do código para se perceber mais facilmente o problema?

Answer (score 0):

Achei a resposta:

```
value.filter(row => { 
   const cnpj = row.cnpj || ''
   return cnpj.indexOf(this.search) >= 0
})
```

Era apenas colocar o valor esperado pelo indexOf numa const

Comment: Talvez te ajude usar o método [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) em vez de indexOf.